# jQuery data being passed back is coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending error messages back to my jQuery/ajax form post, when I alert the data: it passes back:

```
{"success": false, "error": "Security tokens do not match, please try again"}
```

But when I try to get the error message like so:

```
if(!data.success){
        alert(data.error);
}else{
```

The alert passes back undefined. Do I have to initiate a variable with the error first or...?

Sorry, I am new at this.

Here is my jQuery in case anyone needs it:

```
<!-- process add employment form without refreshing, then load the div with the new information !-->
$("#content").on("submit", "#add_employment_form", function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if(!data.success){
                alert(data.error);
            }else{
                $('#add_employment').text("+ <?php echo System::translate("Add employment"); ?>");
                $(".add_qualification_json").slideUp("slow");
                $("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>employment/employment" + " #inner_main_content");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            }
        }
    });
        return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
});
<!-- end process add employment form without refreshing, then load the div with the new information !-->
```

Comment: is `data.success` being returned as a string? i.e. `"false"` rather then `false`. I'd expect it if the data is valid json. `"false"` is `true`(fy)

Comment: That too is being returned as undefined.

Comment: `data` is undefined?

Comment: Did you try the `error: function()` callback? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: the error call back fires if there is an error in the response, i.e. 404

Comment: You haven't told jQuery what data type to expect back - its "intelligent guess" looks like it might be wrong in this case.  See the `dataType` option [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response mime type might be `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. So, its being processed by the javascript function as a normal string and not as a json object.

So, you need to set the right response mime type or do this in your success callback javascript function.

```
success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            .....
```

Comment: Adding `dataType:"json"` as   [James Thorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791010/james-thorpe) mentioned to the ajax call will be a better option.